# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 Changes MSFakes Shim Object Default Behaviour

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-fakes

We have a suite of unit tests some of which use MS Fakes. Prior to Update 4 they ran successfully. After applying Update 4 the tests that instantiate a shimmed type fail with a ShimNotImplemented exception. This has been confirmed by executing the same codebase on two different machines, one with Update 4 the other without.

I understand that it's possible to change the behaviour of a shimmed type between DefaultValue and NotImplemented but from what I can determine prior to Update 4 the default behaviour was DefaultValue. Naively this seems like a breaking change. We will have to change a number of tests to accomodate this.

A brief look through the [MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2994375) on the release of Update 4 makes no mention of changes to MS Fakes.

Incidentally we have encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934260/ms-fakes-unit-tests-failing-after-visual-studio-2013-update-4/26938395#26938395) issue as well and have amended our references. Again there was no mention of this in the release documentation.

Can anyone confirm that the default behaviour of a MS Fakes shim object has changed with VS Update 4 and if so why it has changed?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issues, surprised to not see anyon else reporting it.  I resovled by calling Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimBehaviors.BehaveAsDefaultValue(); in the test Setup.

Comment: Yep @user2050218, this is what we did in the end. Annoying tho, and also true that it doesn't seem to be widely reported.