# Need a work around Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

We been getting this on are most up to date systems VS 12 update 4 we have tried setting specific version to false and still get the test failing with this message

> Product.Business.Test.Providers.AuthenticationProvider.GivenRequestToStoreAuthenticationState_WhenParametersAreValid.ThenItShouldStoreTheAuthenticationState
>   threw exception:  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

can anybody save us from this fake calamity

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31941344/1257607) solved it for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting a similar issue some time back. Re-referencing the test assembly and recreating the Fakes assembly sorted the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks this seamed to fix it i'm very gratful had spent about 3 hours fighting though many other ways that just did not work

Comment: You saved my n number of hours! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This solved it for me:

- deleting the **bin**, **obj** and **FakesAssemblies** folder
- make sure the specific version for the Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes assembly is set to 'false'
- rebuild the test project

Answer (score 2):

After days of fighting this problem in TFS Build, I discovered it is really a runtime error when the unit tests are run by TFS. The key is "or one of its dependencies." The

> Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll

is dependent on

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

so I copied the framework DLL into the `Fakes` directory and checked it in. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below entry in App.config worked for me.

```
<runtime> 
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly> 
     <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/> 
    </dependentAssembly> 
   </assemblyBinding> 
</runtime>
```

Comment: The project that was giving me trouble had that entry in the app.config, only the newVersion which was supposed to be 12.0.0.0 was set to 11.0.0.0 causing half my tests to fail.