# ShimNotImplementedException after upgrading Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft Fakes v12

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-fakes

We are utilizing Microsoft Fakes with Visual Studio 2013. After updating to Visual Studio 2013 Update-4 or Update-5, we are getting `ShimNotImplementedException`'s in our tests.

We have [followed instructions found in other SOF questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934260/ms-fakes-unit-tests-failing-after-visual-studio-2013-update-4) and turned off the `SpecificVersion` of our `Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes` references. This allows a compile but the tests still fail when run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint we needed to solve this was found in [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/72565c64-cb82-4053-86bb-d8414dd89107/shimnotimpletedexception-after-installing-visual-studio-2013?forum=vsunittest).

> The underlying issue is that the legacy tests did not define specific methods
>   on the ShimXXX object that the code based is using. Under version 11
>   all is well; version 12 is a different matter.

The stack trace for the `ShimNotImplementedException` gave the needed information on the missing property/method:

```
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimNotImplementedException
at $Func`2NotImplementedf5b9281e-32b0-4bf3-9079-6a54470670de.Invoke(SiteContext arg1)
at Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.get_Database() //THIS IS THE PROBLEM PROPERTY
at Sitecore.Ecommerce.ShopContext..ctor(SiteContext innerSite)
at ActiveCommerce.UnitTest.ProductStockManagerTests.get_MockShopContext()
at ActiveCommerce.UnitTest.ProductStockManagerTests.GetAvailability_AlwaysInStock()
```

Adding the missing property to our shim construction solved the issue:

```
        return new Sitecore.Ecommerce.ShopContext(new ShimSiteContext
        {
            PropertiesGet = () => new NameValueCollection(),
            DatabaseGet = () => null //ADDING THIS SOLVED THE ISSUE
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to a similar problem after upgrading several of our projects from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5.2 using Visual Studio 2015. All the sudden several previously passing tests started failing. The common denominator was that all of the tests were using Shims to mock registry access.

What appears to have happened is that something changed in the handling of the Dispose method. Originally I had not implemented a Dispose method on the RegistryKey shims. That didn't seem to cause any trouble running under .NET 4. However after the switch to 4.5.2, it is implicitly being called all the time.

The solution was simple: I just added a stub for Dispose.

```
Microsoft.Win32.Fakes.ShimRegistryKey.AllInstances.Dispose = (key) => { };
```

The tests now pass again.

Note that setting it to NULL did *not* solve it for it. There has to be a method.