# Visual studio 2013 update 5 does not have fake method in shim class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method as following :

```
public bool Authorized(Permission requiredPermission, WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity)
{
    return true;
}
```

When I generate fakes assembly for the assembly containing above method , the Shim class does not have the corresponding Func for this method.

But if I generate the fakes assembly for VS2013 update 4 or earlier , it works (i.e have the corresponding `Func<>` in Shim class.

Why is this so ?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: My Question is that why in VS2013 Update 5 , there is no corresponding Func in Shim class ?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31679796/21567) help?

Comment: @Christian.K, No it didn't help. My issue is about a missing Method in Shim class. Thanks for help though..